# Table TD Leaking background through shadow

Tags: html, css, html-table, box-shadow, w3.css

I have made a table and I wish to use shadows to colour code the results leaving them with just the colours is okay but I want to include some separation to make the information more presentable upon doing this it bugs out on Internet Explorer and causes some leaking colour which I don't understand because it works fine on all other browsers.

Here is a link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/fkhw6L08/2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.BackColourYC{
background-color:orange;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px White;
text-align:center!important;
}

td{padding: 20px;}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
<td class="BackColourYC">WOOOO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have been scratching my head at this for some time and cant work out why it is bleeding colour through any help would be fantastic!.

Here is the leaking colour zoomed in so you can see it easily:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/biMS3.jpg]

IE Version 11.

Comment: Not a solution exactly, but is there a reason you are using `box-shadow` instead of just using `border`? That would prevent this issue. Or using `display:table` instead of actual tables. (Although I presume you are using `<table>` for tabular data and not just for layout?)

Comment: It makes me sad that i completely forgot i could just use a border lol. Thanks